# SP Farm not working after windows updates

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-on-prem, cumulative-update

> spadmin, the account used for the SharePoint timer service and the
>   central administration site, is highly privileged and should not be
>   used for any other services on any machines in the server farm.  The
>   following services were found to use this account:
>   SPUserCodeV4(Windows Service)     Distributed Cache Service(Windows
>   Service)

I am not sure if this is what is causing my issues.  I am also not sure which services these are under the service accounts in the Farm Credential Management.  Tried backing off updates but it will not allow me to uninstall the security updates for Microsoft sharepoint enterprise server 2013.

Not sure how to get powerpivot working again for updates to the excel files.

Comment: what error you are getting? did you run the PSconfig wizard after installing the updates? which updates you installed.....you cant uninstall it

Comment: Tried backing off updates but it will not allow me to uninstall the security updates for Microsoft sharepoint enterprise server 2013.

Comment: I am also receiving DistributedCOM errors in my windows system log files.

Comment: I mentioned above...you cannot uninstall it. What error you are getting? Did you run the config wizard after installation of updates.

Comment: These were windows OS updates, not SharePoint updates, correct?  Did you check to see if the SQL Service was running?

Comment: can you provide us more info about what packages have you installed and what excactly doenst working? Thank You

Comment: Any errors in ULS log or Event Viewer about PowerPivot?